# jQuery increase / decrease value on input checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this eCommerce project where I need to calculate "shipping costs" if a particular checkbox is checked.
Here's the code for the checkbox :-

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
<p>Shipping Outside Lagos (N2, 000)</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping" id="shipping">
</div>
```

How can I write the jQuery function, so that when the input is checked..I can get the value in a variable. Suppose the default value is 2000, how would I be able to get $amount=2000 (if checked) and $amount remains 0 if unchecked.
Due to my limited knowledge in jQuery / JavaScript, I'm unable to find a solution for it.
Search didn't help either.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
var amount = $('#shipping').is(':checked') ? 2000 : 0;

$('#shipping').on('change', function() {
     amount = this.checked ? 2000 : 0;
});

// use amount
```

Comment: How would I be able to store the changing values in a php variable so that I could access it for the rest work ?

Comment: @NetStack - PHP is executed on the serverside, long before the javascript executes, so you can't, unless you send the data to the server, either by reloading the page or with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var shippingAmt = 0;
$("#shipping").change(function() {
    shippingAmt = this.checked ? 2000 : 0;
});
```

Comment: How would I be able to access these values outside </script> in a php varaible ?

Comment: With an AJAX call - PHP is server-side and JS is client

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a function to determine the cost of items. You could have an abstract of determining costs which would run through a few or several conditions to calculate 'add ons' so to speak.

So you'd have your initial total of say $500.99, then run that value through something like `calculateTotalValue(value)`

It would check if any add-ons were checked in the form, and add their values to the initial value.

This would allow you to have any number of extras, like shipping, or even add-ons/upgrades for the product itself, and you'd be able to fetch the total without fail in each case. You could have a generic way of stipulating that a field is an 'add on' so you wouldn't need to maintain a list, like so:

`<input type="checkbox" rel="add-on" data-add-on-type="shipping" value="500">`

Then in your function,

```
calculateTotalValue(value) {
    $.each($('input[rel="add-on"]'), function(i) {
        // You probably want some error checking here
        value += this.val();
    });

    return value;
}
```

If necessary you could use `data-add-on-type` to keep track of where costs comes from to output a list for the user, as well.